# file upload script in php not working

Tags: php

My php code for file upload is not working. I have tried it in various ways. My code is given below:
HTML Code:

```
<form action="assets/php/regc.php" method="POST" name="rform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="photo" type="file" placeholder="Attach Photo" required="required"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="" />

</form>

PHP Code:
<?php
$pic=$_FILES["photo"]["name"];

$location="assets/";
$myfile= $location.basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

if(isset($_FILES["photo"]["name"]))
{
    $ok=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $myfile);
    if($ok)
    {
    echo "success"; 
    }

    else
    {
    echo "Failed";  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: form and PHP code in same file or different file ?

Comment: check for errors in `$_FILES["photo"]["error"]`

Comment: form and php code are on different page

Comment: so problem  is with your paths . try to read about relative paths absolute path etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Way:

```
    <?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image" />
         <input type = "submit"/>

         <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
         </ul>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes It's True I just did it, but i know it's working i have used it many times so may it help to solve the problem. Is this any problem regarding this?

Comment: Please See the @Shivangi Vyas answer is directely from `W3school`.

Comment: you need to explain bit more about your answer

Comment: If it is not appropriate to answer this way so i gladly delete it. @JYoThI please tell medam

Comment: also thank you to always-a-learner for sending a working code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

in your input tag also pass id

Comment: what is the need of id here ?

Comment: may it occur to be reason for error so it should be better to pass id also with name

Comment: if not adding id="fileToUpload"  id attribute in html element . it cause error on server side . i don't agree with you .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. It looks similar
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: It looks a bit more w3c but also a awesome resource :D

Comment: Thanks JYoThI and always-a-learner, both of you are right. Now my code is working.